# using cookies with twisted.web.client

Tags: python, cookies, twisted

I'm trying to make a web client application using twisted but having some trouble with cookies. Does anyone have an example I can look at?

Answer (score 7):

While it's true that `getPage` doesn't easily allow direct access to the request or response headers (just one example of how `getPage` isn't a super awesome API), cookies are actually supported.

```
cookies = {cookies: tosend}
d = getPage(url, cookies=cookies)
def cbPage(result):
    print 'Look at my cookies:', cookies
d.addCallback(cbPage)
```

Any cookies in the dictionary when it is passed to `getPage` will be sent.  Any new cookies the server sets in response to the request will be added to the dictionary.

You might have missed this feature when looking at `getPage` because the `getPage` signature doesn't have a `cookies` parameter anywhere in it!  However, it does take `**kwargs`, and this is how `cookies` is supported: any extra arguments passed to `getPage` that it doesn't know about itself, it passes on to `HTTPClientFactory.__init__`.  Take a look at that method's signature to see all of the things you can pass to `getPage`.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out there is no easy way afaict
The headers are stored in twisted.web.client.HTTPClientFactory but not available from twisted.web.client.getPage() which is the function designed for pulling back a web page. I ended up rewriting the function:

```
from twisted.web import client

def getPage(url, contextFactory=None, *args, **kwargs):
    fact = client._makeGetterFactory(
        url,
        HTTPClientFactory,
        contextFactory=contextFactory,
        *args, **kwargs)
    return fact.deferred.addCallback(lambda data: (data, fact.response_headers))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web import client

def getPage(url, contextFactory=None, *args, **kwargs):
    return client._makeGetterFactory(
        url,
        CustomHTTPClientFactory,
        contextFactory=contextFactory,
        *args, **kwargs).deferred

class CustomHTTPClientFactory(client.HTTPClientFactory):

    def __init__(self,url, method='GET', postdata=None, headers=None,
                 agent="Twisted PageGetter", timeout=0, cookies=None,
                 followRedirect=1, redirectLimit=20):
        client.HTTPClientFactory.__init__(self, url, method, postdata,
                                          headers, agent, timeout, cookies,
                                          followRedirect, redirectLimit)

    def page(self, page):
        if self.waiting:
            self.waiting = 0
            res = {}
            res['page'] = page
            res['headers'] = self.response_headers
            res['cookies'] = self.cookies
            self.deferred.callback(res)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    def cback(result):
        for k in result:
            print k, '==>', result[k]
        reactor.stop()

    def eback(error):
        print error.getTraceback()
        reactor.stop()

    d = getPage('http://example.com', agent='example web client', 
                 cookies={ 'some' : 'cookie' } )
    d.addCallback(cback)
    d.addErrback(eback)

    reactor.run()
```